# How to filter posts by date using date range picker in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, date, search, filtering, daterangepicker

I have an input field that uses the date range picker. This input field is part of a search query that is supposed to filter out posts by date range, time, and individual dates.

I have two custom fields, one that users can enter individual dates and times in and one that allows users to choose a date range and time range.

I can't seem to get my meta query to work because when I add a date range in the input field, the address bar formats the date to be yyyy-mm-dd+-+yyyy-mm-dd
and my custom fields format the date to be

*yyyy-mm-dd*

*yyyy-mm-dd - yyyy-mm-dd*

When I remove the '+' in the address bar, posts seem to come up, but it's also not filtering properly. It will show the post regardless if it has the exact format as the date range without taking into consideration the actual date range and I can't get it to display individual dates.

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['lp_s_date']) && !empty($_GET['lp_s_date'])){


function me_search_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search ) {
$meta_query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'exact' => true,
    'sentence' => true,
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
    'key' => 'prefix-mydates',
    'value' => ( $_GET['lp_s_date'] ),
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),

    array(
    'key' => 'prefix-range',
    'value' => ( $_GET['lp_s_date'] ),
    'type' => 'date',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),

);
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
};
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'me_search_query');
```

Second Attempt:

```
if (isset($_GET['lp_s_date']) && !empty($_GET['lp_s_date'])){

$start = ($_GET['start']);
$end = ($_GET['end']);  

 function me_search_query( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_search ) {
$meta_query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
array(
    'key' => 'prefix-range',
    'value' => array($start, $end),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'DATE',
    ),
array(  
    array(
    'key' => 'prefix-myDates',
    'value' => $start,
    'compare' => '>=',
    ),
    array(
    'key' => 'prefix-myDates',
    'value' => $end,
    'compare' => '<=',
    ),
),



);
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
  };
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'me_search_query');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From WP Codex

> value (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array only when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'.
>
> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the
>   date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format.

so, first of all fix it

Comment: Sorry, can you explain further what I'm supposed to fix? Am I not supposed to use 'LIKE' when it's in an array? or is my value not going to get my custom field value unless I turn it into an array?